# I want to make where clause inside to select DB::raw in laravel

Tags: jquery, mysql, laravel, query-builder

I have two tables `biodata_wni` and `demographics`, I want to count data where column `akta_kwn` in `biodata_wni` has value 1 and also the count of `akta_kwn` in `biodata_wni` is 2.

Can anyone have to case like this ?

```
$smstr= $request->semester;  
$kec= $request->kecamatan;

$aktakawin= DB::table('biodata_wnis')
        ->join('demographics', 'biodata_wnis.nik','=','demographics.nik')
        ->where('demographics.nama_kec','=',$kec)
        ->where('biodata_wnis.semester','=',$smstr)
        ->select(
            DB::raw("count(biodata_wnis.akta_kwn) WHERE biodata_wnis.akta_kwn = 1 as jml_lk"),
            DB::raw("count(biodata_wnis.akta_kwn) WHERE biodata_wnis.akta_kwn = 2 as jml_pr")
            , 'demographics.nama_kel')
        ->groupBy('demographics.nama_kel as name')
        ->get();
```

I want to get a result like this:

```
Illuminate\Support\Collection {#1321 ▼
  #items: array:5 [▶
    0 => {#1329 ▶
      +"jml_lk": 21
      +"jml_pr": 1
      +"name": "CARANGSARI"
    }
    1 => {#1323 ▶
     +"jml_lk": 21
     +"jml_pr": 1
     +"name": "CESTSA"
    }
```

Comment: Which Laravel version are you using? I never used two db raws in the same select, but you can try to use selectRaw and remove the DB::raw. Can you add a toSql debug to see how the SQL query it's been rendered?

Comment: i use laravel v7, so that code is the wrong way to make the result that i want, maybe you have the right way to make the result i want ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its the SQL syntax that's the problem, there isn't a SQL syntax where a `WHERE` applies to `COUNT`.

What you can do is:

```
    ->select(
        DB::raw("sum(biodata_wnis.akta_kwn = 1) as jml_lk"),
        DB::raw("sum(biodata_wnis.akta_kwn = 2) as jml_pr")
```

There the `biodata_wnis.akta_kwn = 1` is a 0 or 1 expression depending if its true or not. `sum`ing them up results in the count for that particular item.

Comment: thank you so much, its works